# Pass checkbox values to a delete method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a list of user objects,

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= check_box_tag 'ids[]', user.id, false, :class => 'table-row-checkbox' %></td>
            <td>
              <%= link_to user.email, edit_user_path(user)  %>
            </td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
```

I want to create a link delete and delete all the checked users.

```
    <%= link_to 'Delete', delete_user_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
```

How can I pass all the checked checkboxes to the destroy method ?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your check box in a form:

```
<%= form_tag(delete_user_path,:id => 'form_id',) do %>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= check_box_tag 'ids[]', user.id, false, :class => 'table-row-checkbox' %></td>
            <td>
              <%= link_to user.email, edit_user_path(user)  %>
            </td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
     <%= submit_tag("Delete") %>
<% end %>
```

and when the submit button is pressed you will get the ids in param passed into the controller:

```
"ids"=>["1", "2", "3"]
```

If you don't want to submit button, then you would need to use javascript/jquery:

```
<%= link_to 'submit', "#", :onclick => "$('#form_id').submit()" %>
```

Now your action at controller would look like something like this:

```
def delete
  if request.post?
    delete_ids = params[:ids].collect {|id| id.to_i} if params[:ids]

    delete_ids.each do |id|
       User.find(id).destroy
    end

  end
end
```